# Demonstrating the vanishing of the Ricci tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

Suppose at some point$$R_{ab}v^av^b = 0$$ for arbitrary timelike vectors $v^a$, where $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci tensor.  I am wondering how to show that this implies $R_{ab} = 0$ at this point.

Ray d'Inverno (Introducing Einstein's Relativity, p. 144) suggests this can be shown as follows: let $v^a = t^a + \lambda s^a$, where $t^at_a = 1$, $s^as_a = -1$, $t^as_a = 0$, $\lambda\le0<1$, and with $\lambda$ arbitrary.  Then one can test special coordinate systems such as $t^a = \delta^a_0$, $s^a = \delta^a_1$, followed by similar ones.

I have two questions with this approach:

1. Note $v^av_a = 1 - \lambda^2$.  And yet, $v_a$ is supposed to be a **unit** tangent vector, correct?
2. What good does it do to evaluate $R_{ab}v^av^b$ in various special coordinate systems (which at best implies that only some components vanish), when we need to show that all components of $R_{ab}$ vanish in a single coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy-paste here the exercise for completeness:

> If at some point $P$, the symmetric tensor $R_{ab}$ satisfies
>   $$R_{ab}v^{a}v^{b} = 0$$
>   for an arbitrary timelike vector $v^{a}$, then deduce that $R_{ab}$
>   must vanish at $P$.
>
> [Hint: let $v^a = t^a + \lambda s^a$, where $t^at_a = 1$,
>   $s^as_a = -1$, $t_a s^a = 0$, $0\leq\lambda<1$, $\lambda$ arbitrary, and 
>   consider a special coordinate system in which $t^a=\delta^{a}_0$ and
>   $s^a=\delta^a_{1,2,3}$ in turn.]

So let's go carefully through the assignment. This exercise is a about a (generic) symmetric two-index tensor $R_{ab}$ (that he then applied to the Ricci), which vanishes contracted with timelike vectors (i.e. with vectors $v^a$ such that $v^av_a > 0 $); it is a general identity about tensors rather than a peculiarity of the Ricci.

Let's now follow the hint. As you correctly state, you get that $v_a v^a = 1- \lambda^2$ (this vector does not have unit norm, and there is no need why it should have); in particular it remains timelike for all values of $\lambda$.

Then we just compute what the contraction of $v$ with $R$ is:
$$ R_{ab} v^a v^b = R_{ab} (t^a + \lambda s^a ) ( t^b + \lambda s^b) = R_{ab} t^at^b + 2 \lambda R_{ab}t^a s^b  + \lambda^2 R_{ab} s^a s^b,$$
where, in the last step, we used the symmetry of $R_{ab}$ and we renamed the two indices. Now we compute the previous expression for $t^a=\delta^{a}_0$ and $s^a = \delta^{a}_i$, being $i = 1,2,3 $; we get
$$ R_{ab} v^a v^b = R_{00} + 2 \lambda R_{0i} + \lambda^2 R_{ii} . $$
Since we observed that $v^a$ is timelike for any $\lambda$, we know by hypothesis that this quantity vanishes, i.e.
$$ R_{00} + 2 \lambda R_{0i} + \lambda^2 R_{ii}  = 0.$$

Now we recall that $\lambda$ can assume any value between $0$ (comprised) and $1$; this is enough to say that all the components $R_{00}$, $R_{0i}$ (and by symmetry $R_{i0}$ as well) and $R_{ii}$ are equal to zero. Starting with $\lambda = 0$, we get $R_{00} = 0$, which holds for any choice of $\lambda$; then the equation (restoring $\lambda \neq 0$) reduces to
$$ 2 \lambda R_{0i} + \lambda^2 R_{ii}  = 0,$$
which can clearly be satisfied for any $0<\lambda <1$ only if the two $R$'s vanish.

We have to show now that the mixed-spatial component $R_{ij}$ vanish; this is achieved by considering $s^a = (\delta^a_i + \delta^a_j)/\sqrt{2}$. Going through the same steps, and making use of the already-know-to-be-vanishing components we get $ 0 = R_{ab} v^a v^b = \lambda^2 R_{ij}/2.$

When a tensor vanishes in one frame of reference, it vanishes in all; this is a general property that worth being discussed more. The change of coordinates is reflected on tensors  in a linear nonsingular transformation: we contract indices with the jacobian of the transformation; being the change of coordinates a diffeomorphism, the jacobian is injective, and therefore a tensor vanishes in one system of coordinates if and only if vanishes in all.

---

For completeness, I underline why the hypothesis of the symmetry of $R_{ab}$ is necessary. If it were not the case, we could not simplify the contraction as we did; we would just remain with
$$ R_{ab} v^a v^b = R_{ab} t^at^b +  \lambda ( R_{ab} + R_{ba}) s^a t^b  + \lambda^2 R_{ab} s^a s^b, $$ and here we have nontrivial cancellations between antisymmetric components of $R$: indeed, following the same steps, we would end up with just the *symmetric* part of $R_{0i}$ (i.e.\ $R_{(0i)} = (R_{0i}+R_{0i})/2$) vanishing. (But I am not 100% sure of this very last comment since it is quite late in the night and I had better to go to sleep)

Comment: Note that all frame-depending statements are not covariant, hence there are no sum implied!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!  I see that we only need one (not many) special coordinate systems.  But in the derivation of the geodesic deviation equation, and in the whole surrounding context, $v^a$ is necessarily a unit vector.  Why is this suddenly no longer the case?

Comment: I have not gone through the book by d'Inverno, so I am not really sure of his notation and his conventions. However, it looks to me that the fact that $v^a$ usually represent velocities is not important for the solution of this exercise. Note moreover that you can always rescale the vectors $v^a$ in this exercise to get norm 1, because $1-\lambda^2$ is always non vanishing.

Comment: To complete my previous comment, note that $R_{ab}v^a v^b$ vanishes if and only if $R_{ab} (\alpha v)^a (\alpha v)^b$ ($\alpha \neq 0$) vanishes as well, so what really matters is the fact that $v$ is timelike (and the multiplying factor is non zero).

Comment: We can further investigate the physical meaning of a rescaling of $v$: it corresponds to an affine transformation of the proper time. It is easy to see that this transformation leaves the geodesic equations invariant.

Comment: I just spotted an important typo in my answer; I wrote:timelike vectors (i.e. with vectors $v^a$ such that $v^av_a = +1$)

Comment: Okay.  It seems like we assumed in this solution that the metric $g_{ab}$ is the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$.  Is it true that we are allowed, when choosing our special coordinate system, to choose for it whatever metric we like?

Comment: Good point. I assumed that, since the exercises was using latin indices, we were in locally flat coordinates (the one of the vierbeins), but maybe d'Inverno does not adopt that convention, I should have checked. However, it should be enough to perform the computation in locally flat coordinates, that exists at every point of the manifold (although they are not differentiable!)

Comment: To answer to your question: at every point of you manifold you can introduce flat coordinates (ie coordinates such that the metric gets Minkovski). But keep in mind that they are not differentiable function of the points of the manifold (otherways the manifold itself would be flat). This flat basis is given by the vielbeins